# Is Philosophy ever going to have a design?

Tags: discussion, design

I love designing SE sites, though I am not exactly hired by SE. All I do is make custom styles and let anyone think about it.

In that case, after looking around, this Stack Exchange site is the oldest one to graduate that still doesn't have their custom style. No custom header, color scheme, or background. Nothing. Still the plain proposed site style, and I want to change that.

Are we even going to get a style for Philosophy Stack Exchange?

Comment: There’s a design team at SE for this but tbh I am fond of the blank at this point

Comment: The only thing missing for me is dark mode but that is relevant to all SE. We could perhaps have a philosophical picture as a banner on the front page (like the cathedral) @JosephWeissman

Comment: A relevant post (on this meta) by one of our Community Managers from earlier today: [Custom Philosophy SE design and logo - Information gathering](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5314/31765) :)

Comment: Update: [Your new site design is live!](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5365/31765)